Sprinkler Valve Chaos Bleed Screws
I've got 2 orbit manifolds with 5 valves each. I had one zone stay on when cycling manually through all other zones. When trying to fix this issue, I noticed that opening the bleed screw on any given valve will cause a new zone to start running. It also causes some zones
to stop. It seems very random. Mostly looking for a "why?" on this. What does messing with one zone's bleed screw have to do with other zones? I've got a pump, relay, and Orbit controller with Beehyve.

Irrigation valves can do weird things when line pressure is too low. Have you checked the supply pressure? Also, on the continuum from clear potable water to weed seed- and mussel-laden canal water, what's the quality of your irrigation water?

Your question about other zones "stopping" when you open a bleed screw is a little unclear .... why are those zones running to begin with?  What exactly is the design of your experiment?   But I suggest you abandon this track.  If the only symptom is that one particular zone is staying on when not called for by the controller, it is relatively easy to diagnose and fix.  You need to edit your question to focus on one thing.  EIther give more info about the bad valve, or more info about your bleed valve experiments.

I hadn't thought of pressure. Not sure how to clarify my question. I'm trying to isolate the bad valve but I can't because multiple zones are running at one time. When I open a bleed valve, that impacts pressure and flow on a different zone. I'm wondering why that happens. I can't see it in my mind.
